# Search for name in all namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Does Visual Studio provide a way to search down through each available `namespace` for suggestions when `The type or namespace name '____' could not be found`?

I often forget which `namespace` to use for a particular object.

For example, the code below does not compile, because I omitted `using System.IO;`.

```
using System;
namespace myTest {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Stream fs = new Stream(); // <-- ERROR
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to give you the option of adding the correct `using` statement (if the assembly is known) or prefixing the member with the relevant namespace.

Comment: +1, i didn't know that you could do that with the keyboard like that

Answer (score 2):

Click on the class that's in a different namespace, and you should see a blue square in the corner

[image]

move your mouse over to that blue square, and an Icon should appear.  click on that icon to have a list of options, one of them should be to add the appropriate namespace.

[image]

Comment: You get the same menu when right-clicking and selecting "Resolve".

Answer (score 1):

It provides a floating helper if you hover over the unknown class that is in the referenced libraries. Helper will suggest a namespace to add.